# Show some informations about a current user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Well here I'm trying to build  a web application with ASP.NET MVC, in terms of the interaction with the database I use ENTITY Framework and i'm using forms authentication  too,  i would like to show the username of my current user and  the name of the agency where he works here are my two classes 
user :

```
public partial class UTILISATEUR
{
    public UTILISATEUR()
    {
        this.STATUT_DEMANDE = new HashSet<STATUT_DEMANDE>();
        this.LISTE_NOIR = new HashSet<LISTE_NOIR>();
    }

    public short ID_USER { get; set; }
    public short ID_AGENCE_APPARTENIR { get; set; }
    public string IDENTIFIANT { get; set; }
    public string MDP { get; set; }
    public string ROLE { get; set; }

    public virtual AGENCE AGENCE { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<STATUT_DEMANDE> STATUT_DEMANDE { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LISTE_NOIR> LISTE_NOIR { get; set; }
}
```

}
and Agency :

```
public partial class AGENCE
{
    public AGENCE()
    {
        this.DEMANDE_CRÉDIT = new HashSet<DEMANDE_CRÉDIT>();
        this.UTILISATEUR = new HashSet<UTILISATEUR>();
    }

    public short ID_AGENCE { get; set; }
    public string CODE_AGENCE { get; set; }
    public string ADRESSE { get; set; }
    public string NOM_AGENCE { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DEMANDE_CRÉDIT> DEMANDE_CRÉDIT { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UTILISATEUR> UTILISATEUR { get; set; }
}
```

}

in order to show the username of my current user i used this :

```
<%:HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>
```

but I can't find how to also display the name of the agency where the current user works, if anyone can help me please, I'm still a beginner XD Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In MVC applications you have to use Razor syntax. Razor code blocks are enclosed in @{ ... }

Try:

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

Here you can learn more about it:

[Introduction to ASP.NET Web Programming Using the Razor Syntax (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28c%29)

Comment: Yes and it worked but i need the name of the agency of the current user also not only his username, u see